# Numpy array of distances to list of (row,col,distance)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy, pdist

I have an nd array that looks as follows:

```
[[ 0.          1.73205081  6.40312424  7.21110255  2.44948974]
 [ 1.73205081  0.          5.09901951  5.91607978  1.        ]
 [ 6.40312424  5.09901951  0.          1.          4.35889894]
 [ 7.21110255  5.91607978  1.          0.          5.09901951]
 [ 2.44948974  1.          4.35889894  5.09901951  0.        ]]
```

Each element in this array is a distance and I need to turn this into a list with the row,col,distance as follows:

```
l = [(0,0,0),(0,1, 1.73205081),(0,2, 6.40312424),...,(1,0, 1.73205081),(1,1,0),...,(4,4,0)]
```

Additionally, it would be cool to remove the diagonal elements and also the elements (j,i) as (i,j) are already there. Essentially, is it possible to take just the top triangular matrix of this?

Is this possible to do efficiently (without a lot of loops)? I had created this array with squareform, but couldn't find any docs to do this.

Comment: The answer to all your questions is affirmative. Yes, it is all possible. Start working.

Comment: lol I got it working but it's slow. I have a matrix of size 76800 x 3900. Was just seeing if there was a faster implementation but I think John had a good suggestion going to try that

Answer (score 5):

`squareform` does all this.  Read the docs and experiment.  It works in both directions.  If you give it a matrix it returns the upper triangle values (condensed form).  If you give it those values, it returns the matrix.

```
In [668]: M
Out[668]: 
array([[ 0. ,  0.1,  0.5,  0.2],
       [ 0.1,  0. ,  2. ,  0.3],
       [ 0.5,  2. ,  0. ,  0.2],
       [ 0.2,  0.3,  0.2,  0. ]])
In [669]: spatial.distance.squareform(M)
Out[669]: array([ 0.1,  0.5,  0.2,  2. ,  0.3,  0.2])
In [670]: v=spatial.distance.squareform(M)
In [671]: v
Out[671]: array([ 0.1,  0.5,  0.2,  2. ,  0.3,  0.2])
In [672]: spatial.distance.squareform(v)
Out[672]: 
array([[ 0. ,  0.1,  0.5,  0.2],
       [ 0.1,  0. ,  2. ,  0.3],
       [ 0.5,  2. ,  0. ,  0.2],
       [ 0.2,  0.3,  0.2,  0. ]])
```

You can also specify a `force` and `checks` parameter, but without those it just goes by the shape.

Indicies can come from `triu`

```
In [677]: np.triu_indices(4,1)
Out[677]: 
(array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2], dtype=int32),
 array([1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3], dtype=int32))

In [680]: np.vstack((np.triu_indices(4,1),v)).T
Out[680]: 
array([[ 0. ,  1. ,  0.1],
       [ 0. ,  2. ,  0.5],
       [ 0. ,  3. ,  0.2],
       [ 1. ,  2. ,  2. ],
       [ 1. ,  3. ,  0.3],
       [ 2. ,  3. ,  0.2]])
```

Just to check, we can fill in a 4x4 matrix with these values

```
In [686]: A=np.vstack((np.triu_indices(4,1),v)).T
In [687]: MM = np.zeros((4,4))
In [688]: MM[A[:,0].astype(int),A[:,1].astype(int)]=A[:,2]
In [689]: MM
Out[689]: 
array([[ 0. ,  0.1,  0.5,  0.2],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  2. ,  0.3],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0.2],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ]])
```

Those `triu` indices can also fetch the values from `M`:

```
In [693]: I,J = np.triu_indices(4,1)
In [694]: M[I,J]
Out[694]: array([ 0.1,  0.5,  0.2,  2. ,  0.3,  0.2])
```

`squareform` uses compiled code in `spatial.distance._distance_wrap` so I expect it will be quite fast for large arrays.  Only problem it just returns the condensed form values, but not the indices.  But given the shape,the indices can always be calculated.  They don't need to be stored with the values.

Answer (score 2):

If your input is `x`, first generate the indices:

```
i0,i1 = np.indices(x.shape)
```

Then:

```
np.concatenate((i1,i0,x)).reshape(3,5,5).T
```

That gives you the first result--for the entire matrix.

As for taking only the upper triangle, you might considering trying `np.triu()` but I'm not sure exactly what result you're looking for.  You can probably figure out how to mask the parts you don't want now though.

Comment: The following will work nicely if `x` is nonzero above the diagonal: `i0,i1 = np.triu(x,k=1).nonzero(); X = np.concatenate( (i0,i1,x[i0,i1]) ).reshape(3,len(i0)).T ` but note `X` will be an array of type `float64`, and the indices (e.g. `X[0,0]`, which is equal to `float(i0[0])`) will need to be converted to `int` later to access `x`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this,

```
print([(x,y, value) for (x,y), value in np.ndenumerate(numpymatrixarray)])

output [(0, 0, 0.0), (0, 1, 1.7320508100000001), (0, 2, 6.4031242400000004), (0, 3, 7.2111025499999997), (0, 4, 2.4494897400000002), (1, 0, 1.7320508100000001), (1, 1, 0.0), (1, 2, 5.0990195099999998), (1, 3, 5.9160797799999996), (1, 4, 1.0), (2, 0, 6.4031242400000004), (2, 1, 5.0990195099999998), (2, 2, 0.0), (2, 3, 1.0), (2, 4, 4.3588989400000004), (3, 0, 7.2111025499999997), (3, 1, 5.9160797799999996), (3, 2, 1.0), (3, 3, 0.0), (3, 4, 5.0990195099999998), (4, 0, 2.4494897400000002), (4, 1, 1.0), (4, 2, 4.3588989400000004), (4, 3, 5.0990195099999998), (4, 4, 0.0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want the top triangular matrix for an `[nxm]` matrix where `n>m`?  That will give you `(nxn-n)/2` elements and lose all the data where `m⊖n`.

What you probably want is the lower triangular matrix:

```
def tri_reduce(m):
    n=m.shape
    if n[0]>n[1]:
        i=np.tril_indices(n[0],1,n[1])
    else:
        i=np.triu_indices(n[0],1,n[1])
    return np.vstack((i,m[i])).T
```

Rebuilding it into a list of tuples would require a loop though I believe.  `list(tri_reduce(m))` would give a list of nd arrays.